# Error: unknown tag <:string> in my app

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-constraintlayout

When I try to run a specific app, Gradle doesn't compile and shows this strange error. I searched for the tag in the file but such a tag doesn't exist.
[The exact state of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW8S3.jpg)

> error: unknown tag <:string>. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: unknown
>   tag <:string>., sources=[C:\Users\nEW
>   u.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.0.aar\b3e4ef6bef14a8fe09fa894d105f65d7\res\values\values.xml:3:5-61],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

However, this isn't the case for other apps I built before, they run smoothly without any error. Please tell me what is the remedy. Thank you before-hand.

**EDIT: Newer projects too face the same problem.**

**Edit 2:** When I remove the **implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'** at build.gradle of the app. It shows this error.

> error: unknown tag <:string>.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: unknown tag <:string>., sources=[C:\Users\nEW u.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\375c9cd48ecaf5e9681416f258535c78\res\values\values.xml:3:5-61], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

The files
*C:\Users\nEW u.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.0.aar\b3e4ef6bef14a8fe09fa894d105f65d7\res\values\values.xml:3:5-61*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <attr format="boolean" name="barrierAllowsGoneWidgets"/>
        <attr format="enum" name="barrierDirection">
            <enum name="left" value="0"/>
            <enum name="right" value="1"/>
            <enum name="top" value="2"/>
            <enum name="bottom" value="3"/>
            <enum name="start" value="5"/>
            <enum name="end" value="6"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="boolean" name="chainUseRtl"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="constraintSet"/>
        <attr format="string" name="constraint_referenced_ids"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="content"/>
        <attr name="emptyVisibility">
            <enum name="gone" value="0"/>
            <enum name="invisible" value="1"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="boolean" name="layout_constrainedHeight"/>
        <attr format="boolean" name="layout_constrainedWidth"/>
        <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintBaseline_creator"/>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintBottom_creator"/>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference" name="layout_constraintCircle"/>
        <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintCircleAngle"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_constraintCircleRadius"/>
        <attr format="string" name="layout_constraintDimensionRatio"/>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_constraintGuide_begin"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_constraintGuide_end"/>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintGuide_percent"/>
        <attr name="layout_constraintHeight_default">
            <enum name="spread" value="0"/>
            <enum name="wrap" value="1"/>
            <enum name="percent" value="2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="dimension|enum" name="layout_constraintHeight_max">
            <enum name="wrap" value="-2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="dimension|enum" name="layout_constraintHeight_min">
            <enum name="wrap" value="-2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintHeight_percent"/>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintHorizontal_bias"/>
        <attr format="enum" name="layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle">
            <enum name="spread" value="0"/>
            <enum name="spread_inside" value="1"/>
            <enum name="packed" value="2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintHorizontal_weight"/>
        <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintLeft_creator"/>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintRight_creator"/>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintRight_toRightOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintStart_toEndOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintTop_creator"/>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="reference|enum" name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">
            <enum name="parent" value="0"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintVertical_bias"/>
        <attr format="enum" name="layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle">
            <enum name="spread" value="0"/>
            <enum name="spread_inside" value="1"/>
            <enum name="packed" value="2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintVertical_weight"/>
        <attr name="layout_constraintWidth_default">
            <enum name="spread" value="0"/>
            <enum name="wrap" value="1"/>
            <enum name="percent" value="2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="dimension|enum" name="layout_constraintWidth_max">
            <enum name="wrap" value="-2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="dimension|enum" name="layout_constraintWidth_min">
            <enum name="wrap" value="-2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr format="float" name="layout_constraintWidth_percent"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_editor_absoluteX"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_editor_absoluteY"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginBottom"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginEnd"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginLeft"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginRight"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginStart"/>
        <attr format="dimension" name="layout_goneMarginTop"/>
        <attr name="layout_optimizationLevel">
            <flag name="none" value="0"/>
            <flag name="standard" value="3"/> <!-- for now only direct & barriers -->
            <flag name="direct" value="1"/>
            <flag name="barrier" value="2"/>
            <flag name="chains" value="4"/>
            <flag name="dimensions" value="8"/>
        </attr>
        <declare-styleable name="ConstraintLayout_Layout"><attr name="android:orientation"/><attr name="android:minWidth"/><attr name="android:minHeight"/><attr name="android:maxWidth"/><attr name="android:maxHeight"/><attr name="layout_optimizationLevel"/><attr name="constraintSet"/><attr name="barrierDirection"/><attr name="barrierAllowsGoneWidgets"/><attr name="constraint_referenced_ids"/><attr name="chainUseRtl"/><attr name="layout_constraintCircle"/><attr name="layout_constraintCircleRadius"/><attr name="layout_constraintCircleAngle"/><attr name="layout_constraintGuide_begin"/><attr name="layout_constraintGuide_end"/><attr name="layout_constraintGuide_percent"/><attr name="layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintRight_toRightOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintStart_toEndOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginLeft"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginTop"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginRight"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginBottom"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginStart"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginEnd"/><attr name="layout_constrainedWidth"/><attr name="layout_constrainedHeight"/><attr name="layout_constraintHorizontal_bias"/><attr name="layout_constraintVertical_bias"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_default"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_default"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_min"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_max"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_percent"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_min"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_max"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_percent"/><attr name="layout_constraintLeft_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintTop_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintRight_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintBottom_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintBaseline_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintDimensionRatio"/><attr name="layout_constraintHorizontal_weight"/><attr name="layout_constraintVertical_weight"/><attr name="layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle"/><attr name="layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle"/><attr name="layout_editor_absoluteX"/><attr name="layout_editor_absoluteY"/></declare-styleable>
        <declare-styleable name="ConstraintLayout_placeholder"><attr name="emptyVisibility"/><attr name="content"/></declare-styleable>
        <declare-styleable name="ConstraintSet"><attr name="android:orientation"/><attr name="android:id"/><attr name="android:visibility"/><attr name="android:alpha"/><attr name="android:elevation"/><attr name="android:rotation"/><attr name="android:rotationX"/><attr name="android:rotationY"/><attr name="android:scaleX"/><attr name="android:scaleY"/><attr name="android:transformPivotX"/><attr name="android:transformPivotY"/><attr name="android:translationX"/><attr name="android:translationY"/><attr name="android:translationZ"/><attr name="android:layout_width"/><attr name="android:layout_height"/><attr name="android:layout_marginStart"/><attr name="android:layout_marginBottom"/><attr name="android:layout_marginTop"/><attr name="android:layout_marginEnd"/><attr name="android:layout_marginLeft"/><attr name="android:layout_marginRight"/><attr name="layout_constraintCircle"/><attr name="layout_constraintCircleRadius"/><attr name="layout_constraintCircleAngle"/><attr name="layout_constraintGuide_begin"/><attr name="layout_constraintGuide_end"/><attr name="layout_constraintGuide_percent"/><attr name="layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintRight_toRightOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintStart_toEndOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf"/><attr name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginLeft"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginTop"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginRight"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginBottom"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginStart"/><attr name="layout_goneMarginEnd"/><attr name="layout_constrainedWidth"/><attr name="layout_constrainedHeight"/><attr name="layout_constraintHorizontal_bias"/><attr name="layout_constraintVertical_bias"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_default"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_default"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_min"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_max"/><attr name="layout_constraintWidth_percent"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_min"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_max"/><attr name="layout_constraintHeight_percent"/><attr name="layout_constraintLeft_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintTop_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintRight_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintBottom_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintBaseline_creator"/><attr name="layout_constraintDimensionRatio"/><attr name="layout_constraintHorizontal_weight"/><attr name="layout_constraintVertical_weight"/><attr name="layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle"/><attr name="layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle"/><attr name="layout_editor_absoluteX"/><attr name="layout_editor_absoluteY"/></declare-styleable>
        <declare-styleable name="LinearConstraintLayout"><attr name="android:orientation"/></declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

*C:\Users\nEW u.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\375c9cd48ecaf5e9681416f258535c78\res\values\values.xml:3:5-61*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <flag name="bottom" value="0x50"/>

        <flag name="left" value="0x03"/>

        <flag name="right" value="0x05"/>

        <flag name="center_vertical" value="0x10"/>

        <flag name="fill_vertical" value="0x70"/>

        <flag name="center_horizontal" value="0x01"/>

        <flag name="fill_horizontal" value="0x07"/>

        <flag name="center" value="0x11"/>

        <flag name="fill" value="0x77"/>

        <flag name="clip_vertical" value="0x80"/>

        <flag name="clip_horizontal" value="0x08"/>

        <flag name="start" value="0x00800003"/>

        <flag name="end" value="0x00800005"/>
    </attr><attr format="enum" name="layout_insetEdge">

        <enum name="none" value="0x0"/>

        <enum name="top" value="0x30"/>

        <enum name="bottom" value="0x50"/>

        <enum name="left" value="0x03"/>

        <enum name="right" value="0x05"/>

        <enum name="start" value="0x00800003"/>

        <enum name="end" value="0x00800005"/>
    </attr><attr name="layout_dodgeInsetEdges">

        <flag name="none" value="0x0"/>

        <flag name="top" value="0x30"/>

        <flag name="bottom" value="0x50"/>

        <flag name="left" value="0x03"/>

        <flag name="right" value="0x05"/>

        <flag name="start" value="0x00800003"/>

        <flag name="end" value="0x00800005"/>

        <flag name="all" value="0x77"/>
    </attr></declare-styleable>
<style name="Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="statusBarBackground">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check your String file

Answer (score 19):

Had very similar error. As turned out the reason was related to string array. In your `string.xml` check if you have empty `<string-array>` or something like

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <string name="array_name_item">Some text</string>
    ...
</string-array>
```

You should update `<string>` tag to `<item>` tag like this:

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <item name="array_name_item">Some text</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

Hope it solves your issue, because Android Studio error message is really confusing here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem I faced was a bit different. The only way I resolved this is mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio find the word plz ctrl+shift+f  <:string> you can easily find and remove the : in string tag.

Comment: Thank you but I did try to find the <:string> in the file before posting the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked actually. Since the error was in some file in the .gradle folder I deleted the folder entirely to make a new one by rebuilding the project. That didn't solve the problem, again an error occurred. So, my last resort was to delete every file related to Android and reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. `D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.`

```
    org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:386)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeOfficialDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 1 exception was raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.

D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.

C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml: error: file failed to compile.

    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:62)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.close(WorkerExecutorResourceCompilationService.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:361)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor729.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.

D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.

C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml: error: file failed to compile.
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:56)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.

D:\sdk\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d95b65239054e732d2f45a49e21394d0\res\values-ja\values-ja.xml: AAPT: error: unknown tag <:string>.

C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml: error: file failed to compile.
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteCompileException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:55)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:28)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.Aapt2DaemonManagerService.useAaptDaemon$default(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.run(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:34)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml:4: error: unknown tag <:string>.
C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml:5: error: unknown tag <:string>.
C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml: error: file failed to compile.

    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create(Aapt2Exception.kt:45)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception$Companion.create$default(Aapt2Exception.kt:39)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doCompile(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:155)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.compile(Aapt2Daemon.kt:81)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.compile(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable$run$1.invoke(Aapt2CompileWithBlameRunnable.kt:37)
    ... 89 more
```

then I open the file when I see this log

```
C:\workplace\das-android\Amz4seller\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeOfficialDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ja\values-ja.xml:4: error: unknown tag <:string>
```

content of the error file

```
2<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
3<plurals name="pk_buy_month">
4    <string name="one">%dヶ月</string>
5    <string name="other">%dヶ月</string>
6</plurals>
```

when I delete the line from 3 to 6 content in my file strings.xml 
this problem not see again. but the content is work fine in English strings.xml